# Would it be ok to run "python manage.py syncdb" multiple times towards a database?

Tags: python, django, syncdb

Would it be possible to run
"python manage.py syncdb" mutiple times towards the database?
Will it cause corruption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `python manage.py syncdb` as many times as you want without any database corruption.  It does not alter any existing tables.

[Syncdb documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/#syncdb).

Comment: Thanks catavaran, will it by default skip it, if it's already synced before?
Do you know if there is any documentation that explains this?

Comment: Yes, this command skips tables that already exist in db.  Documentation is available here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/#syncdb